# How to make a Copy of a Project/Solution in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

As title states: How to make a Copy of a Project/Solution in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

It is such a simple option, and it seems to be unavailable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the good news: If you have Blend for Visual Studio 2012 installed, which came with my Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional installation, then you can do the following:

1. Save the project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
2. Open Blend for Visual Studio 2012.
3. Open the project you are working on.
4. Go to File > Save Copy of Project
5. Open copy of project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

And here is your new copy. A few remarks:

- The copy function does act like a Clean Build though, so keep in mind that you need to rebuild everything.
- Also make sure that you select the correct Configuration in Microsoft Visual studio 2012 again.
- You will still need to remove the project itself in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I tried this, and all it did was copy the entire source folder, junk and all.

Comment: Hm.. In 2015 there's no `Save Copy of Project` or anything similar sounding in the File-menu, in either VS or Blend, boo hoo

Answer (score 0):

What I've found to work so far, assume you have a solution folder structure like so:

```
mysolution
    mysolution
    mysolution.sln
```

You then copy (literally Ctrl+C & Ctrl-V) everything so it looks like this:

```
mysolution
    mysolution
    mysolution-copy
    mysolution.sln
    mysolution-copy.sln
```

Open file `mysolution-copy.sln` with a text editor and replace `"mysolution\mysolution.vbproj"` with `"mysolution-copy\mysolution.vbproj"`

Then open `mysolution-copy.sln` file with  Visual Studio and build it...now it should all work again.