# Create Multi-Project Template

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, templates

**Background**

Please consider this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(v=vs.120).aspx

**What I need**

I will need to (re)create multiple sibling solutions that share common logic.

The current solution structure consists of Solution Folders with projects attached under them.

Shared projects are always included as existing projects and reused throughout every other sibling solution.

**The question**

I would like to create a template based on the solution structure I have now, so sibling solutions may be easily created and added upon.

Is the set up described in the above link something that needs to be done manually, or is it possible to generate a template for the entire solution (*similar as for Projects and Items*)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a solution, you want to add a existing project that will be shared among different solutions.

```
Solution Explorer>right click on solution>add existing project
```

for new project just `add new project`

You can create empty solution and use it as a template but truly it is a hassle in vs.

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697108/Visual-Studio-Painlessly-Renaming-Your-Project-and) explaines it.

Or you can use [blend.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293431/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-project-solution-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: My question is how to create/generate a template of the solution structure I already have.

Comment: But do you want to use files and code you already have or just a files structure?

Comment: What I have now is like 1/4th of the entire solution structure, which will be exactly the same for each sibling solution. I'd like to generate a solution template for this, so I can just point & click generate the entire set up.

Comment: like this? http://www.jayway.com/2015/03/13/visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects/